# Help with further simplification

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am attempting to further simplify 3^3^3^3^3^3^3 mod 1000. The period of 3^n is 100, which I have derived from doing the LCM of mod 8 and mod 125. Now I am stuck, and I need some guidance. How is doing 3^3^3^3^3^3^3 mod (the period) supposed to help me?

Comment: So you start with $3^{(\color{red}{3^{3^{3^{\dots}}}})}$ mod $1000$.  To answer that question you look at $(\color{red}{3^{3^{3^{\dots}}}})$ mod what you determined, and to answer that, perhaps you take the tower even smaller and look at the mod of whatever is relevant now, until you eventually get small enough of a tower or modulo that you can answer that question at which point this gives enough information to answer the previous question and thus the one prior to that and so on... answering the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you know that the period of $3^n\bmod{1000}$ is $100$, consider 3^3^3^3^3^3 mod $100$. The period of $3^n\bmod{100}$ is $20$, so consider 3^3^3^3^3 mod $20$. The period of $3^n$ mod $20$ is $4$, so consider 3^3^3^3 mod $4$. The period of $3^n$ mod $4$ is $2$, so hence, 3^3^3^3 mod $4$ is $3$.

And, $3^3\bmod{20}$ is $7$, and $3^7\bmod{100}$ is $87$, and so, the answer is $3^{87}\bmod{1000}$, which is easy to calculate via repeated squaring.

Comment: This is literally such an amazing explanation. Thank you for your wisdom

Comment: also $3^{87}\equiv3\cdot(10-1)^{43}\equiv3\cdot(-1+43\cdot10-43\cdot10^2)\bmod1000$